# Как сделать множественное добавление в бд mysql php pdo?

Tags: php

Как можно сделать множественное добавление в бд?

Есть ту ду приложение. Пользователь заполнил одно поле, затем нажимает на плюс и заполняет второе поле и при нажатии на кнопку Отправить сохраняются в разных ячейках обе записи.

Как можно сделать? Вот такой код написал но не работает:

```html
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO post (id_d, name) VALUES (:id_d, :name)");
$stmt->bindParam(':id_d', $id_d);
$stmt->bindParam(':name',$name);
$in_arr = array("id_d","name");

foreach ($in_arr as $key => $val) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Пример массива?
Я отправляю в бд данные id_d и name
Значения могут быть разые  в зависимости от того что пишет пользователь
Например id_d = 1 , name = Текст1
И так может быть несколько записей

Есть input у которого есть name='name'
И кнопка submit

Как лучше реализовать это? Количество записей может быть любое.

Comment: структура $in_arr неправильная и bindParam() же внутри цикла надо делать))

Comment: у тебя вопрос не как сделать множественное добавление, потому что оно у тебя уже есть. а вопрос "как мне перебрать массив, структуру которого никто не видел". к вопросу надо добавить пример твоего массива. с этого и надо 
 было начинать.

Comment: пример массива - это не долго и путанно словами рассказывать, а **вывод функции json_encode**

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, у тебя пары значений по типу:

| id_d | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Конан |
| 2 | Варвар |

Массив данных входящих у тебя неправильный, у тебя "плоский" массив с индексами 0, 1, 2 и так далее, для этой цели больше подойдет ассоциативный массив ключ-значение.

После подготовки запроса надо внутри цикла вставлять данные в сам запрос и выполнять его.

Пример работы на [https://phpize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=24fed1be10cf3c70c9f197d2aa580d69&sqlses=4214836bef2a1bc8d4310daecd815d79&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57)

```
//масив данных
$input = [
    1 => 'name',
    2 => 'Dale',
    3 => 'Conan'
];

//запрос и подготовка
$query = "INSERT INTO post (id_d, name) VALUES (:id_d, :name)";
$query = $pdo->prepare($query);

//данные сунуть в бд
foreach ($input as $key => $name) {
    $query->execute([':id_d'=> $key,':name'=> $name]);
} 

//проверка
$query = "SELECT * FROM post";
$query = $pdo->prepare($query);
$query->execute();
$response = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($response);
```

Comment: Спасибо.

Вопросик есть. Вот ты в начале указал массив заранее написанный.
Получается если я получаю данные с формы то я должен изменить эти значения на эти: $name = $_POST['name'] и тд. Т.е сначала получаю данные с формы затем уже отправляю.

Comment: @timursites сложно сказать, мало данных для понимания.

Comment: Я отправляю в таблицу данные из формы которые вводит пользователь. Вводит несколько значений в инпут и сохраняет. В таблице все записи сохранены за автором данной записи. В итоге получается id(уникальное), id_d(закрепляем за пользователем), name, created_at. В твоем примере ты подставляешь значения свои, а мне же нужно из формы методом POST